# Unable to go online in force.com ide

Tags: force.com-ide

I just finished setting up eclipse oxygen and created a force.com project successfully, with the basic components like class, page, trigger etc. When I try to "work online" it shows the below error.

[image]

- Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.0
- Force.com IDE 38
- Java 8
- Windows 7 64 bit
- Salesforce Developer Edition

Force.com Ide Log

[image]

Login history
[image]

Please share your suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your username, password, or server URL is incorrect. Right-click on the Project, choose Properties, Force.com, and update your credentials. Once successfully updated, you'll be able to go back online.

Comment: Credentials are correct because they worked when I created the project for the first time. Anyways, I tried updating the creds in project properties and now the project shows online mode but still, my changes are not getting reflected on the server. When I try to save the file explicitly by choosing "save to server", it again says invalid user/pwd/token/locked out.

Comment: @Sethuraman.AR Have you checked the logs? Go to Window > Show View > Other... > Force.com IDE Log Viewer, and let us know what errors you have in the log, if any. Also, check your Login History in Salesforce to see if you have failed logins.

Comment: They give the same message as shown in the error dialog (my previous screenshot). Updated the question with screenshot of the log.

Comment: @Sethuraman.AR What does your login history show in Salesforce?

Comment: Updating question with the screenshot showing login history